# Erro criar banco de dados ASP.Net Core 2.0 - Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Olá, estou tentando criar um banco de dados com SQL Server utilizando o Entity Framework Core, porem esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-DVLQUI3/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tarefas;Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Initial catalog não é uma palavra chave suportada ?!?!?!

Comment: Olá, Utilize este formato de connectionStrings, alterando para seu banco de dados: { "ConnectionStrings": { "Default": "Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\database.mdf; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true" } }

Comment: Troque `Initial Catalog=` por `Database=`. Fonte: [aqui](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)